# Not able to install matplotlib on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm trying to install python-matplotlib on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
The two paths that I've found doesn't lead me to success.

**PATH 1**

if I try:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

I get

```
The following required packages can not be built: freetype
```

And freetype leads is already insalled and even though I cant seem to solve this dependency

**PATH 2**

If I try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

I get that python-tz is *not installable*.

OBS: pytz is already installed in the machine

Either way, I'm on a dead end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing development dependencies (i.e. header files and stuff).  First try

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

Then rinse and repeat the pip installer ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. libfreetype6 is already installed, and libfreetype6-dev is not on my apt-cache. Do you know which repository is it from?

Comment: Plz ignore my comment. deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main was missing from my source.lst